# The problem with the layout of checkbox when using BooleanFieldEditor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am trying to use BooleanFieldEditor instead of Button with style SWT.CHECK. And I am getting the problem with layout of the checkbox.

The significant part of my previous code is:

```java
    Composite projectGroup = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 1;
    projectGroup.setLayout(layout);
    projectGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));

    Button checkBox = new Button(projectGroup, SWT.CHECK);
    checkBox.setText(Messages.getString("WizardNewProjectCreationPage.createEmptyProject")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    checkBox.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
            shouldEmptyProjectBeCreated = button.getSelection();
        }
    });
```

It gives me this result:

[image]

In this case the checkbox has a small indent at the top and the left side.

The significant part of my current code is:

```java
    Composite projectGroup = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().extendedMargins(100, 0, 100, 0).spacing(100, 100).applyTo(projectGroup);
    BooleanFieldEditor emptyProjectCheckbox = new BooleanFieldEditor("createEmptyProject",
            Messages.getString("WizardNewProjectCreationPage.createEmptyProject"), projectGroup);
    //        GridDataFactory.defaultsFor(projectGroup).grab(true, false).span(2, 1).applyTo(projectGroup);
    // emptyProjectCheckbox.fillIntoGrid(projectGroup, 1);
    createEmptyProject = emptyProjectCheckbox.getBooleanValue();
```

**Whatever values I set into extendedMargins() and spacing() methods, the result is the same** - checkbox is located strictly at the level of the upper frame:

[image]

As you can see, in this case indents are smaller than on the first picture. I want to make the same indents as on the first image and want to understand, how to manage the location of BooleanFieldEditor's checkbox relatively to another elements.

Comment: BooleanFieldEditor messes with the layout of its parent since it expects to only be used in the main composite of a FieldEditorPreferencePage where this is OK. Note that you will have to call `load` and `store` manually if you are not in a FieldEditorPreferencePage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using second composite solves the problem:

```
        Composite projectGroup = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().extendedMargins(5, 0, 5, 0).applyTo(projectGroup);

        //intermediate composite, which needs to work around the problem with layout of checkbox of BooleanFieldEditor
        Composite intermediateComposite = new Composite(projectGroup, SWT.NONE);
        BooleanFieldEditor emptyProjectCheckbox = new BooleanFieldEditor("createEmptyProject",
                Messages.getString("WizardNewProjectCreationPage.createEmptyProject"), intermediateComposite);
        createEmptyProject = emptyProjectCheckbox.getBooleanValue();
```